# How to make a one-time payment in Stripe?

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I am trying to make my site do a one time payment and verify, `/payment/confirm` will verify the payment went through and add the item to the current user, and `/pricing` is just the page they were before being redirected to the stripe checkout, this is my code for the payment so far:

```golang
    params := &stripe.CustomerParams{
        Name: stripe.String(usr.Username),
    }
    newCustomer, err := customer.New(params)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    checkout := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{
        Customer:   &newCustomer.ID,
        SuccessURL: stripe.String(host + "/payment/confirm"),
        CancelURL:  stripe.String(host + "/pricing"),
        PaymentMethodTypes: stripe.StringSlice([]string{
            "card",
        }),
        Mode: stripe.String(string(stripe.CheckoutSessionModePayment)),
        LineItems: []*stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
            &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
                Price:    stripe.String(PriceID),
                Quantity: stripe.Int64(1),
            },
        },
    }
    return session.New(checkout)
```

This is my code, For some reason this doesn't work... it says:
"`cannot use checkout (variable of type *stripe.CheckoutSessionParams) as *stripe.BillingPortalSessionParams value in argument to session.New`"

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I need to import `github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72/checkout/session` and I was importing some other session.

```golang
import "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72/checkout/session"
```